# физика вместе с анимацией работает некорректно, что делать?

Tags: unity3d

Я создал пустую анимацию (переходник на основную), включил галочку apply root motion, но когда объект находится на этой анимации, то очень медленно и дёргано опускается, при столкновении ведёт себя, как с отключенной гравитацией. Я хочу, чтобы в момент пустой анимации объект вёл себя как обычно, как решить эту проблему? (В коде никакие параметры аниматора не меняю)

[image: Animator]

[image]